# Как бесконечно проверять интернет в цикле?

Tags: c#, winforms, многопоточность, циклы

Нужно постоянно проверять соединение с интернетом, если нету соединения, сделать действие ( я же отключаю кнопки ) если есть вкл! и.т.д по кругу)
Пробую так:

```
public void RefreshConnect()
{
    new System.Timers.Timer(1000) { Enabled = true }.Elapsed += delegate
    {
        var connected = CheckNet.CheckURL(StrSite.TestConnect);
        while (connected)
        if (connected)
        {
            CheckProcessClose.Enabled = true;
            OffSite4Game.Enabled = true;
            TracePing.Enabled = true;
            Checker4Game.Enabled = true;
            OffSiteForum.Enabled = true;
            SupportGame.Enabled = true;
            MRTDownload.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            CheckProcessClose.Enabled = false;
            OffSite4Game.Enabled = false;
            TracePing.Enabled = false;
            Checker4Game.Enabled = false;
            OffSiteForum.Enabled = false;
            SupportGame.Enabled = false;
            MRTDownload.Enabled = false;
            Refresh();
        }
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { BadConnect.Visible = !connected; }));
    };
}
```

Вызываю в `Form_Load`:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => RefreshConnect());
```

Но проверка идёт долго + контроллы не обновляются + нагрузка сильная.

P.S: ^_^ Да `while(connected)` наверное лишнее)

Comment: именно что лишнее, у вас повторение проверки таймер обеспечивает

Comment: @rdom, но даже его убрать, тоже самое получается)

Comment: нагрузка большая потому что вы начинаете следующую проверку, не дождавшись окончания первой.  Допустимые таймауты HTTP превышают 1 секунду. Ну и код проверки у вас вызывается синхронно, поэтому интерфейс висит

Comment: Проверять в цикле соединение с интернетом негодное решение. Нужно проверять соединение только перед каждым необходимым вам запросом к интернету. Измените логику, не надо связывать между собой доступность интернета и доступность нажатия кнопки. Пользователь нажал кнопку, вы проверяете соединение, если нет соединения, сообщаете об этом пользователю и выходите из метода.

Comment: Проверка соединения с интернетом в цикле - это катастрофа для аккумулятора ноутбука или планшета.

Comment: @Bulson много что - катастрофа для аккумулятора, а на стационарном питании живой мониторинг - вполне валидный вариант, от задачи и ее условий зависит.

Comment: @rdorn я в своих комментариях исходил из того, что проверка соединения ведется с помощью пингования гугла или еще чего подобного, а если это делать еще и в цикле..., ну вы поняли. Да, и канал соединения, в добавок ко всему, забьёте. И другие параллельно работающие программы с интернетом пострадают от этого.

Comment: @Bulson да я же не спорю, просто дополнил. Естественно постоянный мониторинг на стороне клиента еще производительность ресурса посадит, кстати стоит дописать в ответ

Answer (score 2):

Учтите, что если такой мониторинг повесить каждому клиенту, то может пострадать производительность ресурса, который вы собираетесь мониторить. Это имеет смысл только для техподдержки и разработчиков ресурса. У клиента доступность ресурса должна проверяться по требованию, либо с большими интервалами, чтобы не забивать канал спамом от мониторинга.

Заведите отдельный сервисный класс (набросок, модифицируйте под свои задачи)

```
class ConnectionMonitor : IDisposable
{
    private bool urlAvailable = false;
    private bool isActive = false;
    private System.Threading.Timer timer;

    public string Url { get; private set; }

    public event EventHandler ConnectionStateChanged;

    public ConnectionMonitor(string checkingUrl) { Url = checkingUrl; }

    public void Start()
    {
        isActive = true;
        timer = new Timer(CheckUrl, null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
    }

    public void Stop() 
    {
        isActive = false;
    }

    private void CheckUrl(object state) // сигнатура для TimerCalback
    {
        var checkResult = CheckNet.CheckURL(StrSite.TestConnect);
        if(checkResult ^ urlAvailable)
        {
            ConnectionStateChanged.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
            urlAvailable = checkResult;
        }
        timer.Dispose();
        if(isActive)
            timer = new Timer(CheckUrl, null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite); 
    }

    public void Dispose() { timer?.Dispose(); }
}
```

Теперь создаете по монитору на сайт, подписываете в форме на события мониторов, и в событиях меняете состояние кнопок. Проверка будет происходить с интервалом 1 секунда между завершением предыдущей и началом следующей. Метод проверки вызывается в пуле потоков, это обеспечивает таймер.

PS: Писал по памяти, могут быть мелкие ляпы.

Comment: Спасибо, понял что лучше так не делать, как предложил @Bulson, сделать на кнопке пару раз проверку)

Answer (score 1):

Вот тебе пропертя которая будет делать то что тебе нужно

```
private static bool InternetIsConnected
{
    get
    {
        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                using (var stream = client.OpenRead("http://www.google.com"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

вызывай ее так часто, как тебе нужно :)

Но лично я советую вызывать не постоянно в цикле, а только по нужде(в момент когда именно будет нужен интернет.)

Comment: Пригодится) Взял на вооружение)